# List-item with display: flex; and <span> tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list item with `display: flex;` property. The problem is that according to standard behaviour `<span>` tag will be considered as a flex-element. That is why `span` tag stands out. But I need it to be the part of the text or something like this.

**How can I make my span bold without these ugly consequences?**

```
<li class="list__item"><span class="list__item-span">THIS TEXT WILL BE BOLD</span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus laborum rem est vitae inventore, dolorem incidunt voluptate velit impedit odit illum. Placeat dolores, doloribus alias delectus atque debitis? Explicabo, maxime!</li>

        .list__item {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            &::before {
                content: url("../images/check-mark.png"); /*link to the image (https://imgur.com/3XNSHMy) */
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
            &-span {
               font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you need the flex property for in this case (if there are no other child elements)?

Comment: @Johannes, I need the flex property to be able to align my ```::before``` image and the text. Without it it looks not as I would like it to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="list__item"><span><span class="bold">THIS TEXT WILL BE BOLD</span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus laborum rem est vitae inventore, dolorem incidunt voluptate velit impedit odit illum. Placeat dolores, doloribus alias delectus atque debitis? Explicabo, maxime!</span></li>

        .list__item {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            &::before {
                content: url("../images/check-mark.png"); /*link to the image (https://imgur.com/3XNSHMy) */
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
          
        }
        .bold{
           font-weight: bold;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text and span element inside a paragraph.

```
   <li class="list__item"><p><span class="list__item-span">THIS TEXT WILL BE BOLD</span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus laborum rem est vitae inventore, dolorem incidunt voluptate velit impedit odit illum. Placeat dolores, doloribus alias delectus atque debitis? Explicabo, maxime!</p></li>
```

This will fix the issue but not sure if thats how u wanted it to be done.

Comment: thank you, your answer was also useful and worked to me.

Comment: oh wao, nice to hear that,  btw the answer other guy gave will also work but i would recommend not to use multiple same tags, it just does not feel like a good practice. but in the end, its all ur choice.